# Error installing Ruby 2.2.0 with rvm

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm, osx-yosemite

I am using OSX 10.10.2.

I tried using rvm to update Ruby from 2.1.5 to 2.2.0. This resulted in some errors which sent me down a path of troubleshooting problems with Ruby and rvm.

Ultimately, I did a full uninstall of rvm with `rvm implode`. This didn't work and I was instructed to manually remove ~/.rvm. I did so and reinstalled rvm packaged with Ruby 2.2.0. The rvm install was successful. When attempting to install Ruby 2.2.0, the installation keeps failing.

Any ideas on how to solve this error?

**Terminal output:**

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$ rvm --debug install 2.2
ruby-2.2.0 - install
ruby-2.2.0 - #already removed src/ruby-2.2.0
ruby-2.2.0 - #already removed rubies/ruby-2.2.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Remote file does not exist https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
Remote file does not exist https://s3.amazonaws.com/jruby.org/downloads/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
Remote file does not exist http://binaries.rubini.us/osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
Remote file does not exist https://rubies.travis-ci.org/osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
rvm_remote_server_url4 not found
No remote file name found
Remote file does not exist https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
Remote file does not exist https://s3.amazonaws.com/jruby.org/downloads/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
Remote file does not exist http://binaries.rubini.us/osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
Remote file does not exist https://rubies.travis-ci.org/osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
rvm_remote_server_url4 not found
No remote file name found
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Free disk space 22323MB, required 440MB.
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_setup ruby-2.2.0
rvm_autolibs_flag=4
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_movable_early ruby-2.2.0
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_system_early ruby-2.2.0
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_requirements ruby-2.2.0
Checking requirements for osx.
requirements code for osx loaded
requirements lib type set to osx_brew
brew seems to be writable
Found required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libksba, openssl.
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Alex/.rvm/bin
rvm_configure_flags+=( --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml )
rvm_configure_flags+=( --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/readline )
rvm_configure_flags+=( --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libksba )
rvm_configure_flags+=( --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl )
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_movable ruby-2.2.0
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_parse_name ruby-2.2.0
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_system ruby-2.2.0
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_architectures ruby-2.2.0
rvm_architectures(0):.
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_gcc47plus ruby-2.2.0
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_bison ruby-2.2.0
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_flags_docs ruby-2.2.0
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_flags_shared_static ruby-2.2.0
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_flags_threads ruby-2.2.0
__rvm_setup_compile_environment_compatibility_flag ruby-2.2.0
found compiler: gcc
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.0 - #downloading ruby-2.2.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
fetch http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2 => ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2
Archive checksum matched, not downloading
Downloaded archive checksum matched.
Log prefix: /Users/Alex/.rvm/log/1422746529_ruby-2.2.0/
Log filesystem: local,
Log max name length: 250
Log file: /Users/Alex/.rvm/log/1422746529_ruby-2.2.0/extract.log
[2015-01-31 18:22:09] __rvm_package_extract
__rvm_package_extract () 
{ 
    rvm_debug __rvm_package_extract:$#: "$@";
    \typeset __tempdir __path __file __return;
    __return=0;
    __tempdir="$( TMPDIR="${rvm_tmp_path}" mktemp -d -t rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX )";
    __rvm_package_extract_run "$1" "$__tempdir" || __return=$?;
    if (( __return == 0 )); then
        for __path in "$__tempdir"/*;
        do
            __file="${__path##*/}";
            if [[ -n "${__file}" && -e "$2/${__file}" ]]; then
                \command \rm -rf "$2/${__file}" || __return=$?;
            fi;
            \command \mv -f "${__path}" "$2/" || __return=$?;
        done;
    fi;
    if [[ -n "$__tempdir" ]]; then
        \command \rm -rf "$__tempdir";
    fi;
    return $__return
}
current path: /Users/Alex/.rvm/src
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Alex/.rvm/bin
command(3): __rvm_package_extract /Users/Alex/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.2.0.tar.bz2 /Users/Alex/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_21941
ruby-2.2.0 - #extracting ruby-2.2.0 to /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0.....
__rvm_rm_rf already gone: /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0
Patch name 'optional', expanded_name(s) ''.
Patch name 'default', expanded_name(s) 'fix_installing_bundled_gems'.
Patch name 'osx', expanded_name(s) ''.
All found patches(1): fix_installing_bundled_gems.
Patch full path '/Users/Alex/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.0/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch'.
Log file: /Users/Alex/.rvm/log/1422746529_ruby-2.2.0/patch.apply.fix_installing_bundled_gems.log
[2015-01-31 18:22:12] __rvm_patch
__rvm_patch () 
{ 
    \patch "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Alex/.rvm/bin
command(8): __rvm_patch -F 25 -p1 -N -f -i /Users/Alex/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.0/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch
ruby-2.2.0 - #applying patch /Users/Alex/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.0/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
Log file: /Users/Alex/.rvm/log/1422746529_ruby-2.2.0/configure.log
[2015-01-31 18:22:12] ./configure
current path: /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Alex/.rvm/bin
command(5): ./configure --prefix=/Users/Alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
ruby-2.2.0 - #configuring..........................................................
Log file: /Users/Alex/.rvm/log/1422746529_ruby-2.2.0/postconfigure.log
[2015-01-31 18:22:38] __rvm_post_configure_ruby
__rvm_post_configure_ruby () 
{ 
    __rvm_post_configure_ruby_fix_athlon_sse2;
    __rvm_post_configure_ruby_update_setup
}
current path: /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Alex/.rvm/bin
command(1): __rvm_post_configure_ruby
ruby-2.2.0 - #post-configuration.
Log file: /Users/Alex/.rvm/log/1422746529_ruby-2.2.0/make.log
[2015-01-31 18:22:38] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Alex/.rvm/bin
command(3): __rvm_make -j 1
ruby-2.2.0 - #compiling.............................................................
__rvm_rm_rf already gone: /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0/.ext/rdoc
Log file: /Users/Alex/.rvm/log/1422746529_ruby-2.2.0/install.log
[2015-01-31 18:24:30] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Alex/.rvm/bin
command(2): __rvm_make install
ruby-2.2.0 - #installing...........
Error running '__rvm_make install',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/Alex/.rvm/log/1422746529_ruby-2.2.0/install.log
    from /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems.rb:556:in `install'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:717:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:716:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:716:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:749:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:749:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:746:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:746:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Error 1
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
__rvm_rm_rf already gone: /Users/Alex/.rvm/tmp/21941*
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Ran `brew doctor` and found an unlinked keg...

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.4) is outdated
Please install XQuartz 2.7.7:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.0.2209.1.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.0.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libGLEW.1.5.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libintl.8.0.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.62.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpangox-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.2.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libz.1.2.5.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/stdint-msvc2008.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/tree.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-bsd.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-darwin.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-linux.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-sunos.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-unix.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-preparser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libintl.la
    /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpangox-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.la
    /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.la

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libGLEW.a
    /usr/local/lib/libintl.a
    /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
    /usr/local/lib/libportaudio.a
    /usr/local/lib/libz.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    node
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$
```

I then tried running `brew link node` to fix the unlinked keg...

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.30... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/node
Target /usr/local/bin/node
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/node'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

When trying just to remove the source of the issue with `rm '/usr/local/bin/node'`, running `brew link node` again just returned another error, instructing me to remove yet another file, so I decided instead to take the overwrite approach...

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$ brew link --overwrite node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.30... 33 symlinks created
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$
```

Running `brew doctor` again no longer showed the unlinked keg.

Now to reinstall Ruby 2.2.0...

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$  rvm remove 2.2
ruby-2.2.0 - #removing src/ruby-2.2.0..
ruby-2.2.0 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.2.0..
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$  rvm reset
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$  rvm install 2.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.0 - #downloading ruby-2.2.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.2.0 - #extracting ruby-2.2.0 to /Users/Alex/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0....
ruby-2.2.0 - #applying patch /Users/Alex/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.0/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
ruby-2.2.0 - #configuring..........................................................
ruby-2.2.0 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.2.0 - #compiling.............................................................
ruby-2.2.0 - #installing.........
ruby-2.2.0 - #making binaries executable..
Rubygems 2.4.5 already available in installed ruby, skipping installation, use --force to reinstall.
ruby-2.2.0 - #gemset created /Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global
ruby-2.2.0 - #importing gemset /Users/Alex/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems...........................................................
ruby-2.2.0 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.2.0 - #gemset created /Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
ruby-2.2.0 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/Alex/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.2.0 - #generating default wrappers........
ruby-2.2.0 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
Install of ruby-2.2.0 - #complete 
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:~ Alex$
```

I then updated XQuartz after, as originally instructed by `brew doctor`. This is unrelated, though, just making note. Installing the documentation after also was successful.